# Find distribution that has pdf $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}t^{-1/2} e^{-t}$ on the positive reals.

Tags: probability

Is there a well-known prob. distribution (or a combination thereof) that has pdf: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}t^{-1/2} e^{-t}$$
on $t \ge 0$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pdf you listed is known as [$\chi^2$-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $1$ degree of freedom, i.e. it is the pdf $f_X(t)$ of $X=\frac12Z^2$, where $Z$ is the standard normal random variable.

Comment: I get $\frac{t^{-1/2}e^{-t/2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: @Haderlump The $\chi^2$ random variable is defined as $Z^2$, your density is that of $\frac{1}{2} Z^2$. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

It's the $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},1)$ distribution.